# How do I copy Conditional Formatting instead of expanding it? (Format Painter)

Tags: excel, ms-office, conditional-formatting

I can't get my conditional formatting rules to copy using the Format Painter after installing an MS Office update, how else can I copy a rule across multiple rows without expanding the selection?

**Use Case**

I use Conditional Formatting in a variety of ways, but one of my end users is very particular about how they want to see their data. In a hypothetical, they want to compare game to game performance of each player (as an individual). So, I would set up 2 rules for each player where I'd use color scales to show the player's performance (FG% & Points).

**Previous Process**

To speed up the process, I would create it for Player01, then highlight the entire row, use the Format Painter, and select the row for Player02. But, as of MS Office version 16.0.16529.20226 that functionality is broken, where instead of duplicating the rule for the subsequent row, it expands the conditional formatting to include Player01 and Player02. (Player01 Game 1 FG% compared to Player01 Game 2 FG% compared to Player01 Game 3 FG% etc)

How else can I quickly copy the rules for each row, without expanding the rules?

| Player | Game01 FG% | Game01 Points | Game02 FG% | Game02 Points | Game03 FG% | Game03 Points | Game04 FG% | Game04 Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player01 | 35% | 30 | 37% | 13 | 45% | 30 | 37% | 33 |
| Player02 | 42% | 21 | 41% | 18 | 39% | 23 | 44% | 26 |
| Player03 | 18% | 9 | 33% | 16 | 45% | 19 | 36% | 7 |
| Player04 | 27% | 12 | 25% | 8 | 33% | 6 | 37% | 16 |

Excel example image included (different rules for FG% vs Points)

[image: Excel Image]

**What I've tried**

I've done all the troubleshooting I can think of after an update (close the application, restart PC, test in a new file).

Each time I use the Format Painter it will expand the selection to create 1 rule that covers multiple rows.

Oddity - if the columns to which I apply the conditional formatting are immediately next to each other (unlike the example), the format painter works and it will duplicate the rule from row 1 to row 2, without expanding the selection.

One of the challenges is that my user requires a format as presented above. I don't use Macros very often, but I'm always running this on a different number of games, and players, where-as I would expect a Macro to require a consistent number of games.

Comment: Please share what's `Conditional Formatting` for Player01.

Comment: Thanks! The condidtional formatting for Player01 is the first option of the standard "Color Scales" (Green - Yellow - Red Color Scale).

That color scale is used once for FG%, then again for Points. Comparing that player's performance across all of the games where they were able to participate.

Answer (score 0):

Excel (AFAIK all releases) tries to simplify range references by merging adjacent cells with the same rules. I guess the only way is to be set it via VBA rather than through the Excel UI.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim oRng As Range, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim pointRng As Range, percentRng As Range
    Call RemoveFC
    Set oRng = ActiveSheet.[a1].CurrentRegion
    Set pointRng = [C1]
    Set percentRng = [B1]
    r = oRng.Cells(1).Row
    For c = 4 To oRng.Columns.Count
        If Int(c / 2) = (c / 2) Then
            ' Get PG% range
            Set percentRng = Application.Union(percentRng, Cells(r, c))
        Else
            ' Get Points range
            Set pointRng = Application.Union(pointRng, Cells(r, c))
        End If
    Next c
    ' Set FormatCondition for each row
    For r = 1 To oRng.Rows.Count - 1
        SetFCondition percentRng.Offset(r, 0)
        SetFCondition pointRng.Offset(r, 0)
    Next r
End Sub
' Set FormatCondition
Sub SetFCondition(oFCRng As Range)
    oFCRng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    With oFCRng.FormatConditions(1)
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = 7039480
    End With
    With oFCRng.FormatConditions(1)
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = 8711167
    End With
    With oFCRng.FormatConditions(1)
        .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
        .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = 8109667
    End With
End Sub
' Remove all exist FormatCoditions
Sub RemoveFC()
    Dim r As Range, c
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each c In r.FormatConditions
        c.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'll get a chance to test the code today, but I believe you're right about merging adjacent cells. It seems like if you use the format painter for Player01 and paste that formatting to Player03, it works. But, trying to paste that formatting to Player02 will cause the formatting rule to merge across the rows.